# D3JS packed circle layout, padding in relation to parent

Tags: javascript, d3.js, padding, circle-pack

I am looking for a way to add padding between parent and child nodes when using the circle packing layout to allow for labeling non-leaf nodes. This is to allow label intermediate nodes as only labeling the lead nodes like the examples, http://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/pack.html, doesn't expose the level of information that I would like to.

Currently I'm producing this jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/rJC2E/. But as you can see the intermediate labels overlap. Currently my radius is set simply using the following code

```
 node.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", (d) -> d.r)
```

I've attempted altering the radius by multipling by .9, and so forth, but that did not lead to the results I was looking for. Current code in coffeescript is:

```
        d3.json("/distilleries.json", (dat) ->
            svgRoot = d3.select('body')
                    .append("svg").attr("width", "100%").attr("height",1000)
                    .append('g')
                    .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)")

            diameter = 900
            format = d3.format(",d")

            pack = d3.layout.pack()
                    .size([diameter - 100, diameter - 100])
                    .value((d) -> d.size)
                    .padding(10)

            node = svgRoot.datum(dat).selectAll(".node")
                    .data(pack.nodes)
                    .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("offsetWidth", 20)
                    .attr("class", (d) -> if d.children then "node" else "leaf node")
                    .attr("transform", (d) -> "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")

            node.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", (d) -> d.r)

            arc = d3.svg.arc()
                    .innerRadius((d,i) -> d.r - 1)
                    .outerRadius((d) -> d.r)
                    .startAngle(0)
                    .endAngle(2 * Math.PI)


            node.filter((d) -> d.children)
                    .append("path")
                    .style("visibility", "hidden")
                    .attr("id", (d,i) -> "p"+i)
                    .attr("d", arc)

            node.filter((d)-> d.children )
                    .append("text")
                    .append("textPath")
                    .attr("textLength", (d,i) -> 100 )
                    .attr("xlink:href", (d, i) -> console.log(d.name + i); "#p" + i)
                    .attr("startOffset", (d) -> Math.random()*(0.2 - 0.15) + 0.15)
                    .attr("dy", (d) -> if d.children then - d.r else ".3em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text((d) -> d.name)
                    .attr("class", (d) -> 
                                    d.class 
                    )
            node.filter((d)-> !(d.children) )
                    .append("text")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text((d, i) -> d.name)
            )
```

Thank you,

Comment: If you posted the actual code used to generate the chart, it would be easier to help than by looking at generated HTML.

Comment: Done. Thank you for letting me know. I assumed it'd be easier to tell me some approaches from the finished product and I'd work backwards with the code. Hopefully this will work better.

Comment: Have you tried a structure something like parent ( padding-container ( child-1, child-2, ..., child-n ) )? Padding container would be a single circle in the parent at a smaller size. I think when you adjust the radius by 0.9 the packing algorithm is just going to repack using the smaller radius.

Comment: Colin, could you possibly be a little more specific, I'm not sure I understand the padding-container part, where would that be?

You are definitely correct on scaling the radius, that affects every thing. Perhaps I should look at expanding the radius of the encompassing circle, going from bottom up?